# how to assign a set of coordinates in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors in Matlab, I (of integers), J (of integers) and V (of doubles).
I want to assign to a matrix, in positions I_i,J_i, ranging over i, value V_i.

Is that possible?
The problem is that A(I,J) refers to all possible combinations (I_i,J_j) instead of matching the elements in the vector.

Comment: could you please rephrase you question more clearly? it is not clear to me what you mean ranging over i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is this:

```
 A(sub2ind(size(A),X,Y)) = V
```

Try it out, it works like a charm.

The explanation, if you're curious and want it, is simple to follow:

Every matrix in Matlab is stored as a 1d array, a normal vector.

A 2d array is actually stored in memory as a sequence of the first column, followed by the second column, and so on. Because of that, you can index any Matlab array, independent of its dimension, by a linear subscript.

For example:

```
  A =  [1  4  7;
        2  4  8;
        3  6  9 ];
```

Is actually stored as:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

So to access item all you have to do is: (j-1)*num_of_columns + i

Because of that, A(2,3) returns the same as A(8), that is, in this case: 8;

The sub2ind function transforms a list of "subscripts" to linear indexes, given the size of the matrix. Exactly what you want to do.

And with the indexes at hand, it is easy to make the assignment.

Docs:
[sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html)

[Indexing in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html)

Hope I understood you correctly.

I took the time to answer in a long fashion because this is a very important part of Matlab, and a LOT of people overcomplicate the code using the "vector-operating" functions to do things that could be done with normal indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
 M = accumarray([I(:) J(:)], V(:));
```

In this case if you have non-unique combinations of I and J, corresponding values in V will be added together (the default functin is `@sum`). If you need different behavior, pass function as an optional argument to `accumarray` (see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a sparse matrix format? A = sparse(...) has a signature that can be used to coerce your (i,j,value) triples into nonzeros of A, where other entries are structural zeros (require no storage).

If I grokked the question, that is.

I think it would be something like A = sparse(i,j,v), the remaining arguments will default to m := max(i), n := max(j), nzmax := length(v), which is what I imagine you'd want.