# Adjacency matrix from edge list (preferrably in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have a list of triads (vertex1, vertex2, weight) representing the edges of a weighted directed graph. Since prototype implementation is going on in Matlab, these are imported as a Nx3 matrix, where N is the number of edges. So the naive implementation of this is

```
id1 = L(:,1);
id2 = L(:,2);
weight = L(:,3);
m = max(max(id1, id2)) % to find the necessary size
V = zeros(m,m)
for i=1:m
   V(id1(i),id2(i)) = weight(i)
end
```

The trouble with tribbles is that "id1" and "id2" are nonconsecutive; they're codes. This gives me three problems. (1) Huge matrices with way too many "phantom", spurious vertices, which distorts the results of algorithms to be used with that matrix and (2) I need to recover the codes in the results of said algorithms (suffice to say this would be trivial if id codes where consecutive 1:m).

Answers in Matlab are preferrable, but I think I can hack back from answers in other languages (as long as they're not pre-packaged solutions of the kind "R has a library that does this").

I'm new to StackOverflow, and I hope to be contributing meaningfully to the community soon. For the time being, thanks in advance!

Edit: This would be a solution, if we didn't have vertices at the origin of multiple vertices. (This implies a 1:1 match between the list of edge origins and the list of identities)

```
for i=1:n
   for j=1:n
   if id1(i) >0 & i2(j) > 0
       V(i,j) = weight(i);
   end
   end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution:

First put together all your vertex ids since there might a sink vertex in your graph:

```
v_id_from = edge_list(:,1);
v_id_to = edge_list(:,2);
v_id_all = [v_id_from; v_id_to];
```

Then find the unique vertex ids:

```
v_id_unique = unique(v_id_all);
```

Now you can use the **ismember** function to get the mapping between your vertex ids and their consecutive index mappings:

```
[~,from] = ismember(v_id_from, v_id_unique);
[~,to] = ismember(v_id_to, v_id_unique);
```

Now you can use sub2ind to populate your adjacency matrix:

```
adjacency_matrix = zeros(length(from), length(to));
linear_ind = sub2ind(size(adjacency_matrix), from, to);
adjacency_matrix(linear_ind) = edge_list(:,3);
```

You can always go back from the mapped consecutive id to the original vertex id:

```
original_vertex_id = v_id_unique(mapped_consecutive_id);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `sparse`:

```
sparse(id1,id2,weight,m,m)
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion as well. The problem with it is that for this command to work you need the same number of unique ids in the origin and destiny vertex for each edge. Otherwise there's a conformability problem. "sparse" on its own is already a partial victory, but gets me a nonsquare matrix!

I'm thinking I need to create zero-weighted edges for all unique IDs for this idea to work. If this works I'll be, um five stops short of solving the underlying problem for which this is a necessary step. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the node ID numbers are nonconsecutive, why not re-map them onto consecutive integers? All you need to do is create a dictionary of all unique node ID's and their correspondence to new IDs.

This is really no different to the case where you're asked to work with named nodes (`Australia`, `Britain`, `Canada`, `Denmark`...) - you would map these onto consecutive integers first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GRP2IDX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grp2idx.html) function to convert your id codes to consecutive numbers, and ids can be either numerical or not, does not matter. Just keep the mapping information.

```
[idx1, gname1, gmap1] = grp2idx(id1);
[idx2, gname2, gmap2] = grp2idx(id2);
```

You can recover the original ids with `gmap1(idx1)`.

If your `id1` and `id2` are from the same set you can apply `grp2idx` to their union:

```
[idx, gname,gmap] = grp2idx([id1; id2]);
idx1 = idx(1:numel(id1));
idx2 = idx(numel(id1)+1:end);
```

---

For the reordering see a recent question - [how to assign a set of coordinates in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794555/how-to-assign-a-set-of-coordinates-in-matlab/9794955)

You can use ACCUMARRAY or SUB2IND to solve this problem.

```
V = accumarray([idx1 idx2], weight);
```

or

```
V = zeros(max(idx1),max(idx2)); %# or V = zeros(max(idx));
V(sub2ind(size(V),idx1,idx2)) = weight;
```

Confirm if you have non-unique combinations of `id1` and `id2`. You will have to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is close to what you want. However it is probably best to iterate over your edge list instead of the adjacency matrix.

```
edge_indexes = edge_list(:, 1:2);
n_edges = max(edge_indexes(:));
adj_matrix = zeros(n_edges);
for local_edge = edge_list' %transpose in order to iterate by edge
    adj_matrix(local_edge(1), local_edge(2)) = local_edge(3);
end
```

Comment: This is vastly more elegant than my first solution. The problem remains, however; since edge_list(1) may be something like (2430, 305), I'm still making big matrices with phantom vertices.

Thanks for the 90 degree turn in the way I was thinking, though. It's well possible that this new thought model may lead me to the solution.